# Pixela - cannot post graph

Tags: python

I'm new to Pixela, and trying to post a graph with pixela. Following the document, I created a user first which succeeded.

When I tried to post a graph, it returned 200 for "response". For `response.text`, it returned `"{"graphs":\[\]}"...` I'm confused whether it means a success or not, so I tried to check the graph page by visiting webpage https://pixe.la/v1/users/herohaha/graphs/graph1.html. It says no graph exist...

Why there's no graph exist and how can I create graph?
here is my code:

```
import requests 
USER_NAME = "USERNAME" 
TOKEN = "MYTOKEN"

header = { "X-USER-TOKEN": TOKEN }

pixela_endpoint= "https://pixe.la/v1/users/" 
graph_endpoint = f"{pixela_endpoint}/{USER_NAME}/graphs"
user_params = { "token": TOKEN, "username": USER_NAME, "agreeTermsOfService":"yes", "notMinor":"yes", }

graph_params = { "id": "graph1", "name": "test graph", "unit": "minutes", "type": "float", "color": "shibafu" }

response = requests.post(url=graph_endpoint, json=graph_params, headers=header) 
print(response) 
print(response.text)`
```

Answer (score 0):

your variable "pixela_endpoint" ends with a "/" but you have included another "/" right after it in your "graph endpoint" variable.